cube js : Error while creating connection, Model files not found
I am getting error while creating the connection to Postgres using cube playground. I am running cube locally and postgres is running in docker. In the docker log I can see errr as
Error: Model files not found. Please make sure the "model" directory exists and contains model files.


I had the same issue.
I had to revert the current version v0.35 back to version v0.34. This seems to solve the issue.
Seems that the CubeJS team made changes to where the model files are located:
https://cube.dev/blog/cube-core-v0-35-updates-to-data-modeling-and-data-sources
